# list of all words?

Tags: words

I'm building a game with Japanese words, and I wanted to know if there are lists of all words available as a text file to download [Like this, but Japanese](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_alpha.txt)? Ideally, there is no Kanji in it, as the game in question is scrabble, and that would complicate things, especially for my audience, but if such a resource exists, that would be fantastic.

ありがとう　みなさん

Comment: Not to be discouraging, but I'm not too sure how well a Japanese variant of scrabble would work, since there aren't many (reasonably long) mora (i.e. Hiragana) combinations that don't form any word, at least when compared to letter combinations in English. Especially if you go by similar definitions of "word" as in English scrabble.

Comment: Also, I think this question would be more suited for the meta SE.

Comment: The idea behind the game is to.build vocabulary for grade 12 students, so the words don't have to be too long, but I appreciate the feedback. As for the Meta site, how come you recommend going there?

Comment: I mean that for this sort of request about resources rather than the language itself the Meta (of this Stack Exchange) would be more suited. Though a mod can move this thread, if they think so.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for informing me

Comment: @Garbaz [Scrabble-like games are possible in Japanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotoba_no_Puzzle:_Mojipittan). This game has a dictionary of >130K words including famous place names and person/character names. Unfortunately it's not available for download for free.

Comment: So the idea behind my game is to act as a vocabulary training tool. So while it is based on scrabble, there are subtle differences which articles like this one greatly help with

Comment: @naruto Interesting! Adding restrictions through pre-placed letters is a clever idea to make it more challenging. Also the "fill all the spots on the board" challenge seems quite indicative of the issue I meant. I don't think you could do the same in English scrabble (though I don't know for sure).

Comment: That would involve being able to make a word from any combination of letters though, right? Since Hiragaga is a syllabrary, that's possible, but alphabetic languages need some sort of pattern of arrangement, so you wouldn't be able to fill every space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a ready made list, but you could take some raw dictionary file like for example [JMdict](https://www.edrdg.org/jmdict/edict_doc.html#IREF01), and extract all the readings using either XML parsing or some Regex.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'll look into it and keep you posted